# Vue 3 components not importing other vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, components, vuejs3

My Vue component `navbar.vue` does not import other components.

This is Vue 3 with the Option API.

All of the components are imported by `index.js` in the component folder

```
import navbar from '@/components/navbar.vue'
import btn from '@/components/btn.vue'

export {
  navbar,
  btn
}
```

This is the `navbar.vue`:

```
<template>
  <header class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <btn></btn>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
import { btn } from '@/components'

export default {
  name: 'navbar',
  components: {
    btn
  }
}
</script>
```

This is the `btn.vue` components:

```
<template>
  <button class="btn" @click="$emit('click')">
    <slot/>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'btn'
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your index.js exported `navbar` and `btn`. And also you have already exported another component from `navbar.vue` in same file level. So make a separate folder for `navbar` and `btn` or change the export name.
I am new to frameworks. Hope this will work.